# how to call a trigger in c# to update a table from other tables

Tags: c#, database, triggers

Suppose i have wrote a trigger like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trupdatetemp
AFTER UPDATE ON dictionnaire_temp
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN if new.REGLE != old.REGLE and new.TYPE_INPUT !=   old.TYPE_INPUT and new.CHAMPS != old.CHAMPS
then
    UPDATE bi_dictionnaire d
   set d.REGLE = new.REGLE , d.TYPE_INPUT = new.TYPE_INPUT ,d.CHAMPS = new.CHAMPS
   where d.ID = new.ID;
end if;END;
```

---

Now i want to call this trigger on Button_Click event in c# window page.
Thanks.

Comment: is trigger has to be called externaly?

Comment: Issue an `UPDATE` to a record in `dictionnaire_temp`.  A trigger isn't something you invoke directly, it happens in response to another action.  To invoke it, invoke that other action.  If it's something you need to call directly, make it a stored procedure.

Comment: No , i want to call it in c# code ! also I do not know where I have to put this trigger !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a stored procedure.
and call it on that click event.